# What is the proper name for this type of washer?

Tags: washer

I'm trying to find a replacement for a washer / spacer that I lost, and it looks like this:

[image]

I know I need one that's M5 in size, and can probably measure the length of the one I've got remaining. But I have no idea what the 'correct' name for this is, so don't know what to search for. Collared spacer? Insert washer?

Answer (score 2):

Using google image search, your photo is used on a UK company's web site:

https://titanclassics.com/product/m6-washer-spacer

They call it a washer spacer, however, that term is not very definitive:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22washer+spacer%22&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22spacer+washer%22&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=washer+spacer&iax=images&ia=images
More definitively, they are called "flange bushings" or "flanged bushings":

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flange+bushing&iax=images&ia=images

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=flanged+bushing&iax=images&ia=images

Somewhat less definitively are "step washers" or "stepped washers" and  "shoulder washer"

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=step+washers&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stepped+washers&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=shoulder+washer&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 1):

I might call it a flanged bushing, except that searching for that term comes up empty. In the past, I posted [an answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131570/protecting-3-16-wire-rope-going-through-poles/131577#131577) to a question that is unrelated to this one, but for the result:

[image: steel protector sleeve]

It's called a steel protector sleeve and common sizes from my search are 1/4" inch and smaller inside diameter. M6 is close to 1/4" but is not M6. The next common size downward is 3/16" which is 4.7 mm, perhaps closer to M5. This may be a result of my searches based in the USA, or that metric versions do not exist, which is somewhat absurd to consider.

I popped off a quick search to [McMaster-Carr](https://www.mcmaster.com/#flanged-sleeve-bearings/=1d7ps6q) with results appearing for flanged sleeve bearings, which are available in M5 inside diameter but are lubricated for taking rotational and axial loading.

Comment: You lead me in the right direction! I think I have the answer, have posted separately. A steel protector sleeve looked right, but the only available lengths were quite long, whereas I'm after something only a few mm long. It's a spacer, rather than a sleeve.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. From https://www.accu.co.uk/en/165-washers-spacers - this seems to be called a *shoulder washer*.